# Subdomain does not redirect to a specific folder

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean

I have in Digital Ocean 3 A record domain:

- Type: **A** Hostname: **mysite.com** Value: **My Server IP**
- Type: **A** Hostname: **www.mysite.com** Value: **My Server IP**
- Type: **A** Hostname: **api.mysite.com** Value: **My Server IP**

In **/var/www/html** I have two folders:

> **Home** is the folder when my user go when he type *www.mysite.com* or *mysite.com*
>
> **Api** is the folder when my user go when he type *api.mysite.com*

In **/etc/apache2/sites-available** I have three files:

**000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/home
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**mysite.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mysite.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/home
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**api.mysite.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName api.mysite.com
        ServerAlias api.mysite.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/api
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I enter on *mysite.com* or *www.mysite.com* I see the contents of my **home** folder. Great!

But when I enter on **api.mysite.com** I'm redirected to **www.api.mysite.com** (something that was not supposed to happen) and I see the contents of my **home** folder (Instead of **api** folder).

In my case I have 2 things to solve:

1. When it enters mysite.com it should be directed to the home folder, and when it goes into api.mysite.com it should be directed to the api folder.
2. When the user types www in my URL, it should be automatically
   redirected to the same URL without the www.

I try to **restart apache**, `a2ensite` but nothing happens, can someone give me a light?

Comment: Are you sure that `api.mysite.com` is in DNS and not `www.api.mysite.com`? My guess is that the browser puts "www" in front of the hostname because it's not in the DNS.

Comment: Yes @neuhaus I'm sure about this, I have a DNS api.mysite.com that go to My server IP